# ContextUpdateHandler interface does not work for a specific context

Tags: java, plugins, sparql, graphdb

I tried to catch a specific context/named graph by implementing following function of the ContextUpdateHandler interface:

```
@Override
public Resource[] getUpdateContexts() {
   getLogger().info("getUpdateContexts");
   Resource[] res = new Resource[2];

   res[0] = () -> "";
   res[1] = () -> "http://example.com/testGraph";

   return res;
}
```

When I make an insert or delete to the default graph, it works perfectly and it gets me into the handleContextUpdate() method where I can further process the update request. However, when I do any insert or delete on a specific context, say http://example.com/testGraph, it does not get recognized. Do you know what might be the problem?

I also tried to write it like this: `<http://example.com/testGraph>` and it didnt work

These are my queries:

```
# Does not work.
delete data { 
    graph <http://example.com/testGraph> { 
        <http://example.com/s/deleteThis2> 
        <http://example.com/p/deleteThis2> 
        <http://example.com/o/deleteThis2> }
}

# Works perfectly fine.
delete data { 
        <http://example.com/s/deleteThis2> 
        <http://example.com/p/deleteThis2> 
        <http://example.com/o/deleteThis2> 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `res[1] = new SimpleIRI("http://example.com/testGraph");`?

Answer (score 0):

Or check the backend code for route differentials
And try adding / to path